# Better way to determine if value exists in JSON feed

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using the `org.json.JSONObject` (and parser) in an Android app to parse a JSON feed. Which is the best way to determine if a property exists or not in one of the objects returned?

Say I have a JSON feed including "News". Some of the news have a property called "UnpublishDate" (which is the date the news in question is no longer active), while some of the news don't have this property.

The best solution I've come up with (though not implemented yet) is to simply have a "try-catch" around the `theJSONObject.get("UnpublishDate")` - do you know of any better solution (that is more graceful when the class scales to several "optional" properties in the JSON feed)?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You might use the `JSONObject` function `has`:

```
if(myJSONObject.has("UnpublishDate")) {
    //it has it, do appropriate processing
}
```

Comment: it is to check if that object contains key, but how to find it contains value for it?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda if it has a key, it has a value.  It's up to you to decide whether the value is acceptable

Comment: how do I check it contains value or not??

Comment: @ShylendraMadda how do you define "contains value"? not null?  my previous comment should give you the answer...

Comment: but here in my case I have key but there is no value, so how to find it? It doesn't contains value with that key?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda sounds like you have some invalid JSON